# Need interpretation of error:'PointCloud2' object has no attribute 'channels'

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Need interpretation of error

```
 [ERROR] [WallTime: 1427306405.964789] [396.335000] bad callback: <bound method TranslatePCL.callback of <__main__.TranslatePCL instance at 0x7f1e81cab638>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 702, in _invoke_callback
        cb(msg)
      File "/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/prrbot_control/src/prrbot_odometry.py", line 259, in callback
        pcl_out = self.transformPointCloud("/rrbot/camera_frame", msg)
      File "/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/prrbot_control/src/prrbot_odometry.py", line 264, in transformPointCloud
        return self.listener.transformPointCloud(target_frame, point_cloud);
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 219, in transformPointCloud
        r.channels = point_cloud.channels
    AttributeError: 'PointCloud2' object has no attribute 'channels'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205896/need-interpretation-of-error:%27pointcloud2%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27channels%27/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would seem instances of class `PointCloud2` don't have a member variable called `channels`.

That is what the error tells you.

---

Edit:

> ah...I was looking for a deeper insight...like what are channels and why is transformPointCloud looking for them.

Well, then you should've stated your question differently :).

In any case, see [ros/geometry/tf/listener.py, lines 207 to 226](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/a0f6b863bfebc95af57ee1b7e38caafdb469e744/tf/src/tf/listener.py#L207-L226) for the source of `transformPointCloud`:

```
def transformPointCloud(self, target_frame, point_cloud):
    r = sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud()
    r.header.stamp = point_cloud.header.stamp
    r.header.frame_id = target_frame
    r.channels = point_cloud.channels
    ...
```

it does more, but I've copied the relevant bit here.

The method essentially makes a copy of `point_cloud` (but transformed into `target_frame`). In order to do that, it needs to copy all fields of the incoming msg. It copies the `header` field first, then the `channels` field, and finally goes on to copy all points in the cloud (in `point_cloud.points`) while simultaneously transforming them.

As to what are channels, see the [sensor_msgs/PointCloud.msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) documentation:

```
# Each channel should have the same number of elements as points array,
# and the data in each channel should correspond 1:1 with each point.
# Channel names in common practice are listed in ChannelFloat32.msg.
```

From the error msg it would appear that you are trying to pass an instance of `PointCloud2` to `transformPointCloud(..)`, which it doesn't seem to support. `PointCloud2` msgs don't have a `channels` field (see [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)).

The requirement for the `point_cloud` parameter to be an instance of `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` is also stated in the documentation of `transformPointCloud(..)`:

```
:param target_frame: the tf target frame, a string
:param ps: the sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud message
:return: new sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud message, in frame target_frame
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-25**:
ah...I was looking for a deeper insight...like what are channels and why is transformPointCloud looking for them.